# How can I reference a constructor from C# XML comment?

Tags: c#, xml, constructor, comments

Is it possible to reference a constructor from a C# XML comment without resorting to the explicit prefixes (like M: or T:)?

For instance, the following yields compilation warnings, because the compiler does not like ".ctor". Trying "PublishDynamicComponentAttribute.#ctor" is no good,
"PublishDynamicComponentAttribute.PublishDynamicComponentAttribute" is no good too.

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructs a new <see cref="PublishEntityAttribute"/> instance.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="PublishDynamicComponentAttribute..ctor(Type)"/>
public PublishEntityAttribute(Type entityFactoryType) :
  base(entityFactoryType)
{
}
```

I am sure the type itself is visible.

So, I am left to use the explicit prefix M:, which removes the compiler verification, so when a type is moved/renamed the cref will be invalid.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You specify a constructor as if you are calling it, but with the types of the arguments instead of values for them:

```cs
/// <seealso cref="PublishDynamicComponentAttribute(Type)"/>
```

Comment: Is this definitely right? Resharper 7.0 warns "Incorrect signature of '<class name>'" and its 'Show Quick Documentation' command treats it as a class link.

Comment: @Iain: It works on my R# 7.0, including linking to the constructor and not the class.

Comment: Weird, I definitely get the warning. Maybe different inspections enabled, maybe a R# bugfix...

Comment: It's a little confusing because you don't get the intellisense to help you complete it as you do with other members, but once you complete it, it properly links to the constructor.  This is of course in modern VS (2022 as I write this); when this answer was originally written, I believe no intellisense or linking existed within XML docs.